# Online result search aplication first html page should render the form and second page will show the data. Help Appricated?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Django, I have two HTML pages first is index.html which shows the home page along with the search field and the second HTML form is the result which shows the desired result which is search by the user. I have already written code that is working fine on only one page but I want to redirect the home page once the user fillup the details it should go to the next page called result.html.

**modles.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

# Create your models here.




class ResultQuery(models.Model):
    os_choice = (
        ('Windows 10', 'Windows 10'),
        ('Windows 8', 'Windows 8'),
        ('Linux', 'Linux'),
    )
    operating_system = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True, choices=os_choice)

    level = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    program = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    exam_year = models.IntegerField()
    institute = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    reg_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    symbol_num = models.IntegerField()
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dob = models.DateField()
    sgpa = models.TextField()
    result = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    subject1_code=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject1_title=models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject1_credit_hour=models.TextField()
    subject1_grade_point=models.TextField()
    subject1_grade=models.TextField()
    subject1_remarks=models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    subject2_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject2_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject2_credit_hour = models.TextField()
    subject2_grade_point = models.TextField()
    subject2_grade = models.TextField()
    subject2_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    subject3_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject3_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject3_credit_hour = models.TextField()
    subject3_grade_point = models.TextField()
    subject3_grade = models.TextField()
    subject3_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    subject4_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject4_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject4_credit_hour = models.TextField()
    subject4_grade_point = models.TextField()
    subject4_grade = models.TextField()
    subject4_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    subject5_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject5_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject5_credit_hour = models.TextField()
    subject5_grade_point = models.TextField()
    subject5_grade = models.TextField()
    subject5_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    subject6_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject6_title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    subject6_credit_hour = models.TextField()
    subject6_grade_point = models.TextField()
    subject6_grade = models.TextField()
    subject6_remarks = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
       return smart_text(self.name)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from search.models import ResultQuery
from django.forms import MultipleChoiceField, ChoiceField, Form
class ResultForm(forms.Form):
      Reg_No = forms.CharField(label="Registration Number")
      Name = forms.CharField(label="Your Name")
      OS = forms.ChoiceField(choices=ResultQuery.os_choice)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ResultForm
from .models import ResultQuery



def home(request):
    form=ResultForm(request.POST or None)
    template_name = "index.html"
    context = {"form": form}
    if form.is_valid():
        objects = ResultQuery.objects.filter(reg_no=form.cleaned_data['Reg_No'], name=form.cleaned_data['Name'], operating_system=form.cleaned_data['OS'])
        context['objects'] = objects

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

**index.html**

```
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>online</title>

    <meta name="description" content="Source code generated using layoutit.com">
    <meta name="author" content="LayoutIt!">

    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



    

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" id="top">
            <div class="col-md-12">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" id="h4">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="logo">
                    <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" srcset="">
                    <br>
                    <h1 class="a">Saj University School of Management</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="h4">
                    <h4>Online Result Form</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="top">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <form action="" method="POST">

                         {% csrf_token %}
                            {{form|crispy}}
                        <select class="amrit" name="cars" id="cars">
                            <optgroup>
                            <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>Select an Institution</option>
                            <option value="management">School of Management</option>
                            <option value="engineering">Faculty of Engineering</option>
                            <option value="science">Faculty of Science and Technology</option>
                        </optgroup>
                          </select>
                          <br>
                          <select class="amrit" name="cars" id="cars">
                            <optgroup>
                            <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>Select a level</option>
                            <option value="management">Bachelor</option>
                            <option value="engineering">Master</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <select class="amrit" name="cars" id="cars">
                            <optgroup>
                            <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>Select a Program</option>
                            <option value="management">BBA</option>
                            <option value="engineering">MBA</option>
                            <option value="engineering">BHM</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <select class="amrit" name="cars" id="cars">
                            <optgroup>
                            <option value="none" selected disabled hidden>Select a Semester</option>
                            <option value="management">1st</option>
                            <option value="engineering">2nd</option>
                            <option value="engineering">3rd</option>
                            <option value="third">4th</option>
                            <option value="firth">5th</option>
                            <option value="sixth">6th</option>
                            <option value="seventh">7th</option>
                            <option value="eight">8th</option>
                        </optgroup>
                        </select>
                        <br>
                        <input type="search" placeholder="Exam Year" name="year" id="year">
                        <br>
                        <input type="search" placeholder="Symbol Number" name="year" id="year">
                        <br>
                        <input type="search" placeholder="DOB(YYYY-MM-DD)" name="dob" id="year">
                        <br>
                        <button type="submit" id="year" name="search">Search</button>
                      </form> 
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" id="sliderbor"> <!--slider start-->
                    <div class="hero">
                    <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
                        <img class="mySlides" src="{% static 'img/inaki-del-olmo-NIJuEQw0RKg-unsplash.jpg' %}" style="width:100%">
                        <img class="mySlides" src="{% static 'img/inaki-del-olmo-NIJuEQw0RKg-unsplash.jpg' %}" style="width:100%">
                        <img class="mySlides" src="{% static 'img/inaki-del-olmo-NIJuEQw0RKg-unsplash.jpg' %}" style="width:100%">
                        <img class="mySlides" src="{% static 'img/inaki-del-olmo-NIJuEQw0RKg-unsplash.jpg' %}" style="width:100%">
                      
                        <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
                        <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
                      </div>
                    


                      <script>
                      var slideIndex = 1;
                      showDivs(slideIndex);
                      
                      function plusDivs(n) {
                        showDivs(slideIndex += n);
                      }
                      
                      function showDivs(n) {
                        var i;
                        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                        if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
                        if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
                        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                          x[i].style.display = "none";  
                        }
                        x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                      }
                      </script>


                        <!--slider end-->
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12" id="h6">
                    <h3><b>Announcement</b></h3>
                    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" id="mymarquee" scrollamount="10">
                        <h4>Brothers and Sisters, the time has come for each and every one of you to decide whether you are going to be the problem or whether you are going to be the solution! (That's right!)
                            You must choose Brothers, you must choose!It takes five seconds, five seconds of decision, five seconds to realize your purpose here on the planet!
                            It takes five seconds to realize that it's time to move, it's time to get down with it! Brother</h4>
                        </marquee>
                        <input type="button" value="&#9208;" onClick="document.getElementById('mymarquee').stop();">
                        <input type="button" value="&#9654;&#65039;" onClick="document.getElementById('mymarquee').start();">


    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" id="h4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="top1">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                </div>
            </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" id="footer">
                <p>© 2021 Sajtheme, Nepal | All Rights Reserved.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" id="h4">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="top13">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                </div>
            </div>

    
</div>

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/scripts.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

{% endblock content %}

**result.html**

```
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Result</title>

    <meta name="description" content="Source code generated using layoutit.com">
    <meta name="author" content="LayoutIt!">

    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="logo">
            <img src="{% static 'img/logo.png' %}" alt="" srcset="">
            <h4>Saj University School of Management</h4>
            <h5>(An Autonomous Institution)</h5>
            <h6>Surkhet, Nepal</h6>
            <br>
            <h6 style="text-decoration: underline;">Grade Sheet</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div style="clear:both;" class="col-md-4" id="p1">
            <p>Name: Amrit Shahi</p>
            <p>DOB: 1994-10-22</p>
            <p>Level: Master</p>
            <p>Semester: First</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;" class="col-md-4" id="p2">
            <p>Regd. No: xxx-xx-xx-xxxx</p>
            <p>Exam Roll No: 256225</p>
            <p>Programme: MBA</p>
            <p>Exam Year: 2020</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table" id="bro">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            S.N
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Course Code No. 
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Course Title    
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Cr. Hr. 
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Grade Point 
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Grade
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Remarks
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            MGT 511 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Foundation of Managmeent    
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            3   
                        </td>
                        <td>3.67</td>
                        <td>A-</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="table-active">
                        <td>
                            2
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            MGT 512 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Critical Thinking   
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            3
                        </td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>B-</td>
                        <td></td>
                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="table-success">
                        <td>
                            3
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            MGT 513 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Communication for Managers  
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            3
                        </td>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>B-</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="table-warning">
                        <td>
                            4
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            MGT 514 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Financial Accounting    
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            3
                        </td>
                        <td>3.33</td>
                        <td>B</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="table-danger">
                        <td>
                            5
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            MGT 515 
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Research Methodology    
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            3
                        </td>
                        <td>2.5</td>
                        <td>C</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="table-active">
                        <td colspan="3">Total Credit Hour and Semester Wise Grade Point Average </td>
                        <td>18</td>
                        <td>3.2</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="8" class="par"><center>Result: Passed</center></td>
                    </tr>
                    
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/scripts.js' %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
{% endblock content %}
```